# Add object to list with strings

Tags: java

I have the following definition which is fine

```
private List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

But now I need to extend it that the first string should be also type list.
I have tried with the following code,add new list and change the first string to hold
the listPrents but I got some error.

```
private Map<String, String> listParents = new HashMap<String, String>();
private List<Map<listParents, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

How can I do something like that ,the lists types can be changed .

Thanks,
Fedor

Comment: Did you call `Map<String, String>` as `listParents`? Do you mean `list` or `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<Map<List<String>, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<List<String>, String>>();`

But generally I would discourage using a list to be the key in a hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an object as a Class Type (you try to use `listParents` instance to define a map of string to string inside a map. I guess you come from the `c` world where you can `typedef` your structures but in this case you should follow one of the answers posted with the correct definition as `Java` does not support typedefs

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is impossible and not even senible in java since generics are realy only syntactic sugger. At compiletime no type checking will be done on those collections. The generics just force you to only use classes that correspond to the given type in a generic.
You can do either:

```
private List<Map<List<?>, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

and you can specify ? further by using the extends  and super keywords, to define a class that fits the structure.

Or the easier solution:

```
private List<Map<List<Object>, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```